# Referencing const objects/pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

There's something I don't quite understand with how references are handled in C++:

```
B objB = B();                   // Regular B object
const B &refConstObjB = objB;   // Reference to const B object

B* ptrB = new B();              // Regular pointer to B
B* const &refPtrConstB = ptrB;  // Reference to const pointer to B
```

All of the above compiles just fine. However the following doesn't:

```
const B* &refConstPtrB = ptrB;  // Reference to pointer to const B
```

Considering both the object and the pointer were declared as non-const, why can I reference the object as a const object, but can't do the same with the pointer?

Comment: By the way, my variable names are wrong! refConstPtrB and refPtrConstB should be inverted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to note: A `const` reference does **not** imply a `const` object.
It simply means an object that is **read-only** through that reference. So whether or not an object is `const`, you can have a read-only reference or pointer to it.

Now, if what you mentioned were allowed, you could say `refConstPtrB = pointer_to_some_const_B`, and then *mutate* that object through `ptrB`, which would violate the `const`-ness of the pointer's target.

Comment: I see! Declaring refConstPtrB give us no guarantee that the data that is being pointed is constant. I would have to declare a pointer to a constant B object for refConstPtrB to be legal. I should have spotted this! Oh well, I guess I'm tired!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error is that you can put a hole in the type system with it.  Consider the following code:

```
const B dontChangeMe;
B* ptrB = new B();

/* This step is NOT legal. */
const B* &refConstPtrB = ptrB;

/* Uh oh!  I now have ptrB pointing at dontChangeMe! */
refConstPtrB = &dontChangeMe;
```

Consequently, you can't do the assignment that you marked.

Hope this helps!